# change references of child elements so the amount of children for parents is the more or less equal

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table `item` and table `container` that represents the storage of item (basically parent is container and item is a child)

```
item --------------------------
item_id | item_type | item_name | container_id

container ---------------------
container_id | container_type
```

I can calculate the amount of items in each container like this

```
select container_id, count(item_id) from container
join item on item.container_id = container.container_id
group by container_id
```

Assuming I have results like this

```
container_1 | 100
container_2 | 1700
container_3 | 200
container_4 | 1000
container_5 | 2500
```

I want to move all items from one container to another in order to create containers where *the amount of items no more than 2500 and remove other containers*

Basically the final result I want to achieve is to get

```
-- containers 2, 3 are removed
container_1 2000 -- it can container_2, doesn't matter
container_4 1000
container_5 2500
```

How to achieve that in SQL?

Comment: Do you have to do this in pure SQL?  My guess is that you would not a function or proc, at least.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yeah, using function or procedure is not a problem

Comment: This is quite a lot of code. Have a go at it yourself and come back with a specific problem - SO is not a freelance, no-cost code writing service. As a suggestion for an algorithm: select all containers where 2500 - container count > 0, ordered by count desc (fill up fullest ones first). Taking containers in order of lowcount to highcount, update container of the lowest (eg container_1) items so they're maximally assigned to the fullest ( container 2) container, until container_2 is full, then move on to putting them in container 4 (next fullest)

Comment: You need a recursive CTE to solve this.  An iterative solution would not be much slower (although iterating in the database using recursive CTEs saves all the round-trip overhead of a non-database solution).

Comment: @CaiusJard I don't expect it as one line of course. I just have no idea how I can tackle that using SQL. Thanks for advice.